# invalid json resulted by foreach loop

Tags: php, json

says I want to get a value of something and store in into an arr to produce json :

```
foreach($item as $items){
   $items = $someting->name;

$arr = array(
   'itemName'=>$items
);

    echo json_encode($arr);

};
```

and it resulted

```
{'itemName':'shoe}{'itemName':'toy}{'itemName':'ball}
```

it's missing the semicolon at the back..

Comment: Add all you want to output in a php array. Then call json_encode once at the end

Comment: @AlexBarroso you mean outside the loop? then I got a single result

Comment: How come there's no closing quote for your `'shoe`, `'toy` and `'ball`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases json_encode should be called once only. Keep adding all you want to convert to JSON in a php array, then call json_encode

```
$json = array('items' => array());
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $json['items'][] = array(
       'itemName' => $item->name
    );
};

echo json_encode($json);
```

You could also call json_encode for all your $items array without doing a loop

`json_encode($items)`

Comment: It's a way of organizing the data so in JavaScript you'll have all your items in data.items (assuming the json response is parsed into a variable named "data")

Comment: First line is confusing? Well jeez, I wonder why you don't find the rest confusing then .. It's just assigning an array with a key which again holds an array.